# RuntimeError: concurrent poll() invocation using celery

Tags: docker, concurrency, celery

When running Celery on a Docker container which receives restAPI from other containers I get a RuntimeError: concurrent poll() invocation.

Did anyone face a similar error?

I attach the traceback.

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 914, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/threading.py", line 862, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/opt/www/api/api/training_call.py", line 187, in start_process
    result_state.get(on_message=self._on_raw_message, propagate=False)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/result.py", line 226, in get
    on_message=on_message,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 188, in wait_for_pending
    for _ in self._wait_for_pending(result, **kwargs):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 255, in _wait_for_pending
    on_interval=on_interval):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 56, in drain_events_until
    yield self.wait_for(p, wait, timeout=1)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/backends/asynchronous.py", line 65, in wait_for
    wait(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/celery/backends/redis.py", line 127, in drain_events
    message = self._pubsub.get_message(timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 3135, in get_message
    response = self.parse_response(block=False, timeout=timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/client.py", line 3034, in parse_response
    if not block and not connection.can_read(timeout=timeout):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/connection.py", line 628, in can_read
    return self._parser.can_read() or self._selector.can_read(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/selector.py", line 28, in can_read
    return self.check_can_read(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.5/dist-packages/redis/selector.py", line 156, in check_can_read
    events = self.read_poller.poll(timeout)
RuntimeError: concurrent poll() invocation
```

Comment: The issue is bubbling up from an exception in the core Python library, through Redis.  Here's where it was discussed https://bugs.python.org/issue8865 and added to the core python code https://hg.python.org/cpython/rev/4543408e2ba6

Comment: @Gianfranco: I do face a similar error (same stacktrace starting at "celery/result.py", line 226")

Comment: @Laizer: the bug you mention has been fixed in 2013 ; Gianfranco seem to use python3.5, and I use python 3.6.6 - both versions seem to include that fix. Any other idea ?

Answer (score 1):

The broker connection is not thread-safe, so you need to handle thread-safety in your application code.
*@Laizer mentioned the [ticket](http://bugs.python.org/issue8865) where this error was introduced in the python core library*

One way to do it is to wrap all the calls that block until task completion in shared Lock:

```
import celery
import threading

@celery.shared_task
def debug_task(self):
    print('Hello, world')

def boom(nb_tasks):
    """ not thread safe - raises RuntimeError during concurrent executions """
    tasks = celery.group([debug_task.s() for _ in range(nb_tasks)])
    pool = tasks.apply_async()
    pool.join() # raised from here

CELERY_POLL_LOCK = threading.Lock()

def safe(nb_tasks):
    tasks = celery.group([debug_task.s() for _ in range(nb_tasks)])
    pool = tasks.apply_async()
    with CELERY_POLL_LOCK:  # prevents concurrent calls to poll()
        pool.join()

def main(nb_threads, nb_tasks_per_thread):
    for func in (safe, boom):
        threads = [threading.Thread(target=func, args=(nb_tasks_per_thread, )) for _ in range(nb_threads)]

        for a_thread in threads:
            a_thread.start()

        for a_thread in threads:
            a_thread.join()

main(10, 100)
```

This is a naive approach, that's suitable for me because I don't expect much concurrency and all the tasks are relatively fast (~10s).
If you have a different "profile", you may need something more convoluted (e.g. a single polling task that periodically polls for all pending groups / tasks).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error come up with an application that was using Redis pub/sub directly.  Firing off many calls to `redis.client.PubSub.getMessage` in quick succession led to this race condition.  My solution was to slow down the rate of polling for new messages.

Comment: Hi @laizer, How did you do that?

Comment: I was calling `getMessage` directly on every request to my web app.  I put in a global counter that fired every 100 requests.

Answer (score 0):

I was faced the same problem, and solved it by

```
pip install -U "celery[redis]"
```

hope it's helpful to you
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/getting-started/brokers/redis.html